# Nodejs for-loop create dynamic routes with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using Express I want to know how I can go about dynamically adding routes using Node. I have routes that I need generated after users input some info into my `element`, and I've been trying to get this done via For Loops.

What I have found is that the routes themselves work. However, the data that is meant to be assigned to them (in this case `elementdata[i]`) does not follow the for loop. By the time `elementdata[i]` is called, `i === elementarray.length`.

My code looks something like this.

```
        for (i = 0; i < elementarray.length; i++){
                app.get("/"+element[i], function(req, res){
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                    res.write(elementdata[i]);
                    res.end();
                });
        }
```

Comment: you can use prams in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` variable keep changes, so you will get only the last value of it (`elementarray.length`)

```
for (i = 0; i < elementarray.length; i++){
    addRoute(i)                
}

function (i){
    app.get("/"+element[i], function(req, res){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write(elementdata[i]);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

If you move it to separated function, every time it will be bound to copy of `i` value

alternatively you can do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < elementarray.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            app.get("/"+element[i], function(req, res){
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.write(elementdata[i]);
            res.end();
        })})(i);
}
```

This will create a clone of i` variable each time.

Answer (score 2):

you fetch data accordingly

```
app.get('/:element', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.params.element);
});
```

here is the documentation for this [EXPRESSJS](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot add dynamic path this way because app.get() in this case is async function, so this will give you bad result - (read about async function in loop)
In this way you should use parameters, like:

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(req.params.id);
    res.end();
})
```

Good explanation here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

this is expected because when your route is called 'for loop' is finished and i === elementarray.lenght and sitting in the global execution context. Define 'i' using 'let' that will solve your issue. Then it will create multiple 'i' value and attached to app.get() execution context.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < elementarray.length; i++){
                app.get("/"+element[i], function(req, res){
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                    res.write(elementdata[i]);
                    res.end();
                });
        }
```

Comment: I've tested this. it is working as expected. Let me know if you able to resolve it by this